# ¿Cómo pasar una función como parámetro de un método en C#?

Tags: c#

Estuve tratando de esta manera:

```
public void agregarUC(Boolean IsNuevo, string metodoInsertar, string tipo)
    {
        if (IsNuevo == true)
        {
            DialogResult opc = MessageBox.Show("¿Realmente Desea Agregar Este " + tipo + "?", "Sistema Restaurante", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (opc == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (metodoInsertar == "OK")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(tipo + " Insertado Correctamente", "Sistema Restaurante", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(tipo + " Existente Actualmente", "Sistema Restaurante", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Y lo llamo de Esta Manera:

```
FrmPrincipal.Instancia.agregarUC(ucCategoriaInsumo.Instancia.IsNuevo,insertarCategoriaInsumo(),"Categoria");
```

Es un método que retorna una cadena.
El problema radica en que siempre se ejecuta el método sea cual sea la respuesta que se le de al `DialogResult`.
Espero que puedan ayudarme gracias.

Comment: que metodo se ejecuta?

Comment: el método "insertarCategoriaInsumo" es el que quiero mandar de parámetro  o a cual te refieres?

Comment: lo que pasa.. es que se esta ejecutando antes de llamar a esa funcion.. lo estas ejecutando al llamar a la funcion AgregarUC.. no despues...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondiendo la pregunta por partes, un ejemplo sencillo seria

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Method1(string input)
    {
        //... do something
        return 0;
    }

    public int Method2(string input)
    {
        //... do something different
        return 1;
    }

    public bool RunTheMethod(Func<string, int> myMethodName)
    {
        //... do stuff
        int i = myMethodName("My String");
        //... do more stuff
        return true;
    }

    public bool Test()
    {
        return RunTheMethod(Method1);
    }
}
```

Llevándolo al caso que presentas, seria algo como :

```
public void agregarUC(Boolean IsNuevo, Func<string, int> metodoInsertar, string tipo)
    {
      // ... do stuff
    }
```

Y se llamaría de la siguiente manera

```
FrmPrincipal.Instancia.agregarUC(ucCategoriaInsumo.Instancia.IsNuevo,insertarCategoriaInsumo,"Categoria");
```

Comment: yo le aclararia que tiene que ejecutarlo cuando if (opc == DialogResult.OK)

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias encerio me funciono de maravilla

Answer (score 1):

Solo sería necesario utilizar el [Delegado Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public void agregarUC(Boolean IsNuevo, Func<string> metodoInsertar, string tipo)
{
    if (!IsNuevo) return;

    DialogResult opc = MessageBox.Show("¿Realmente Desea Agregar Este " + tipo + "?", "Sistema Restaurante", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (opc != DialogResult.OK) return;

    if (metodoInsertar() == "OK")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(tipo + " Insertado Correctamente", "Sistema Restaurante", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(tipo + " Existente Actualmente", "Sistema Restaurante", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

Y al momento de llamarlo:

```
FrmPrincipal.Instancia.agregarUC(ucCategoriaInsumo.Instancia.IsNuevo, insertarCategoriaInsumo, "Categoria");
```